# Rules which produce just terminals

Tags: antlr4

I am wondering if this is a bug in version 4:

```
grammar EntitySQL;

SELECT: 'SELECT' ;

WS: (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r')+ -> skip;

ID: NameStartChar NameChar* ;

NameStartChar: 'a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_';
NameChar: NameStartChar | '0'..'9';

ALIAS: ID ;

r: SELECT ALIAS ;
```

If I test with SELECT PIPPO it claims mismatch for ALIAS.
If I replace the rule with:

```
r: SELECT ID ;
```

it works. Apparently I cannot have rules where the non-terminal just translate to a terminal node?

Comment: Did you get any warnings? Your grammar is ambiguous. `PIPPO` is an `ID` first, not an `ALIAS`.

Comment: You are right. Apparently moving the rule ALIAS: ID; before the ID rule makes it work.

Comment: @Paperino changing the order of `ALIAS` and `ID` will only work for `r: SELECT ALIAS ;`, but it will then break for `r: SELECT ID ;`

Comment: So I found out the issue.
Rules that start with a capital letter are lexer rules (ALIAS : ID). If I change it into (alias : ID) it works as expected.